# Watir/Ruby - Loop through a search results list - search for element ,if element found - action and exit loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir-webdriver

I currently have a list of search results that I want to loop though and find a particular element. This element can occur multiple times(from a few to thousands) but I just want to find the first instance of the element,click it and then exit my loop.

Tried the following but think i am a bit off

```
i = 0
@browser.div(:id=>"resultsList").lis.each do|li| -- loop through list
@browser.link(:href=>"linkname").exists --- check if element exists
@browser.goto(@browser.link(:href=>"linkname") --if it exists click

break if i == 1 ---then break out of loop

end
```

Any pointers would be appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: What does the HTML look like? What element are you looking for, specifically? What do you want to do when it is not found?

Comment: Aplogies should clarify: I have a returned list of adverts, that can be bookmarked. Some adverts on the list may have been bookmarked by the user already. I want to test that teh bookmarking functonaluty is working so want to find the first advert that occurs in the list that has NOT been bookmarked already and click it. i have tried @browser.div(:id=>"resultsList").link(:href=>"linkname").click but webdriver does not find the bookmark element if an advert occuring before it has been bookmarked already i.e. advert1 - Bookmarked advert2 - can be bookmarked

Comment: How do you know which links are bookmarked already? If you could share some of the HTML, it would help make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to loop through the elements. By default, Watir-Webdriver will return the first matching element.

Just do:

```
@browser.div(:id=>"resultsList").link(:href=>"linkname").click
```

This will click the first link in the search results that has the href of "linkname". Note if you actually want the link text (not href) to match "linkname" it should be `link(:text=>"linkname")`.